# How to test class for element type in an empty ArrayList?

Tags: java

So I have a generic ArrayList passed from parameter.

For example:

```
private <T> void testClass(ArrayList<T> data){
  if(data[0] instanceof Foo){
    //do something
  } eles if(data[0] instanceof Bar){
    //do something else
  }
}
```

But the arraylist does not guarantee to have an element inside and could be empty, and `get(0)` will raise exception. How can I do this?

---

Edit:

How about non-initiated generic array?

For example:

```
private <T> void testClass(T[] data){
  if(data.get(0) instanceof Foo){
    //do something
  } eles if(data.get(0) instanceof Bar){
    //do something else
  }
}
```

I tried `T.class.getName().equals("Foo")` but it does not work...

Comment: how about checking the length of the arraylist and only call the get if  the size is >0??

Comment: 1) `T.get(0)` should be `data.get(0)`, and 2) you can check the size of your before making the call, with the appropriately named `size()` method.

Comment: @Perception thanks its a typo. But I also want to check the type even it is empty?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to tell the difference between an empty `ArrayList<String>` and an `ArrayList<Integer>`.  That's quite deliberate, due to type erasure.  (That's because there *is* no difference, at runtime.)

Arrays are different.  At least as long as the array was actually initialized with the literal type, you can use `array.getClass().getComponentType()`.